# MySQL Error - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures, pivot

I am using MySQL with PHP, Codeigniter. I had a question which was answered by bluefeet in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012098/mysql-show-data-in-pivot-view/16013046#16013046)

I created a stored procedure for the second solution by bluefeet. It works perfect, however, while the procedure is called in the production environment, all the other users get the error

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Not sure how can i overcome with this error. I also tried closing the connection after the procedure is called, however, Queries from other users are executed before the connection is closed. Any work-around for this issue?

Below is the stored procedure that i have used

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mailbox.circle_pending_p;
CREATE PROCEDURE mailbox.`circle_pending_p`()
BEGIN
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(CASE WHEN maildate = ''',
      date_format(mailtime, '%e-%b'),
      ''' THEN 1 else 0 END) AS `',
      date_format(mailtime, '%e-%b'), '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM circle_pending_temp
WHERE mailtime >= (select date_sub(max(mailtime), interval 8 DAY)
                   from circle_pending_temp);

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT coalesce(email_Circle, ''Grand Total'') Circle,
              max(`< 9 days`) `< 9 days`, ', @sql, ' ,
              count(*) GrandTotal
            from
            (
              select c.email_Circle,
                date_format(c.mailtime, ''%e-%b'') maildate,
                coalesce(o.`< 9 days`, 0) `< 9 days`
              from circle_pending_temp c
              left join
              (
                select email_Circle,
                  count(*) `< 9 days`
                from circle_pending_temp
                where mailtime <= (select date_sub(max(mailtime), interval 8 DAY)
                                    from circle_pending_temp)
              ) o
                on c.email_Circle = o.email_Circle
              where c.mailtime >= (select date_sub(max(mailtime), interval 8 DAY)
                                      from circle_pending_temp)
            ) d
            group by email_Circle with rollup ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
```

The PHP that i use for calling this procedure is

```
    $db = $this->load->database('mailbox',TRUE);
    $res = $db->query('Call circle_pending_p()');
    echo $db->_error_message();
    $db->close();
    $db = $this->load->database('mailbox',TRUE);
    if ($res->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $res->result_array();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got the Answer! It seems like codeigniter's mysql driver has bugs handling stored procedures.

I changed the drivers from mysql to mysqli in the **config/database** file by changing

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

to

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

Post that i modified the **system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_result.php** file and added the below function

```
function next_result()
{
  if (is_object($this->conn_id))
  {
      return mysqli_next_result($this->conn_id);
  }
}
```

and modified the model as below

```
$db = $this->load->database('mailbox',TRUE);
$qry_res = $db->query('Call circle_pending_p()');

echo $db->_error_message();
$res = $qry_res->result_array();

$qry_res->next_result();
$qry_res->free_result();

if (count($res) > 0) {
      return $res;
} else {
      return 0;
}
```

This solved the problem!

Comment: If using mysqli, you could just call mysqli_next_result($this->db->conn_id); after the procedure call, from the model itself, instead of having to modify the mysqli library

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<?php
while($dbms->more_results() && $dbms->next_result())
    {
        $result = $dbms->store_result();

        if(is_object($result)){ $result->free(); }

        unset($result);
    }
?>
```

After procedure call. `MySQLi` can't call another procedure, while has previous results.
You should use `free()` for each of them before any further procedure call or query execution.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: This is not working! It worked once, but getting the error message again! :(

Comment: You should do it after **ANY** `SQL procedure` call and obtainment of it's results. I don`t know how it should look while using you `database wrapper`. Still, you probably closed `DB connection` here: `$db->close(); $db = $this->load->database('mailbox',TRUE);`. I don't think it needed there.

Answer (score 0):

In file

```
system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_result.php
```

Add:

```
function next_result()
{
    if (is_object($this->conn_id))
    {
        return mysqli_next_result($this->conn_id);
    }
}

function result($type = 'object')
{
    $result = array();

    if ($type == 'array') $result = $this->result_array();
    else if ($type == 'object') $result = $this->result_object();
    else $result = $this->custom_result_object($type);

    $this->next_result();

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similary problem when I was running stored procedure in a loop. The below code I was using:

```
foreach ($month_list as $month_row) 
{

  $start_date = $month_row->adate;
  $end_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last day of " . date("F", strtotime($start_date)) . " " . date("Y", strtotime($start_date))));

  $qry_res = $this->db->query("call staff_attendance('$start_date', '$end_date')");

  $res = $qry_res->result();

  $qry_res->next_result();
  $qry_res->free_result();

  $compiled_months[] = $res;

}
```

In this case the temporary table I created was being complained as table already exists.

So, used this approach instead:

```
foreach ($month_list as $month_row) 
{

  $start_date = $month_row->adate;
  $end_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last day of " . date("F", strtotime($start_date)) . " " . date("Y", strtotime($start_date))));

  $compiled_months[] = $this->db->query("call staff_attendance('$start_date', '$end_date')")->result();
  $this->db->close();
  $this->db->initialize();

}
```

Now execution was perfect